# Waiting for user input in vim script with tab autocompletion

Tags: vim, wildcard

I would like to use a variable in an 'execute', and then complete the command with user inputs. And this must work with tab autocompletion.

Here is the function I work on:

```
function! VimFindRoot()
  execute ':e ' . g:VimGrepFolder . '/**/'
endfunction
```

But when it execute, it does not wait for user inputs.

If I try to do it directly on remap:

```
noremap <C-i> ':e ' . g:VimGrepFolder . '/**/'
```

But it will not replace 'g:VimGrepFolder' with the variable value, but it will wait for user input.

I know about the "input('', '')" function, but it will not work with tab autocompletion.

Do you know how I can make this work like I would?

Comment: FYI: `input()` can accept a completion mode as the third parameter. See `:h input()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<C-r>=expression` then `<CR>` to insert `expression` in the command-line. `expression` can be a variable, a function…

```
nnoremap <C-i> :edit <C-r>=g:VimGrepFolder<CR>/**/
```

See `:h c_ctrl-r_=`.

Comment: I didn't know <C-r>, thank you, that works perfectly!